# How to force use the front camera when the rear camera is not working?

Tags: samsung, camera, 9.0-pie

I have Samsung Galaxy J4+ (SM-J415F). When I try the stock Camera app and also more than 10 camera apps from Play Store, all of them crashed. The rear camera is showing null, but the front camera is normal.

[image]

Is there a way I can only use the front camera?